# Which one is common "they are leftover cigarettes" or "they are cigarette butts"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, idiomatic-language

Look at this picture.

[image]

Do we say "they are leftover cigarettes" or "they are cigarette butts"?

> **[leftover](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/leftover_1?q=leftover)** (adj): that has not been eaten or used at the end of something
>
> - Use any leftover meat to make a curry.
>
> **[butt](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/butt_2)** (noun) the part of a cigarette or cigar that is left after it has been smoked
>
> - an ashtray full of cigarette butts

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leftover%20cigarettes%2Ccigarette%20butts&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccigarette%20butts%3B%2Cc0) does not show any data on "leftover cigarettes".

---

**In addition**, what if you have a cigarette & you smoked by 20% of it, then stopped smoking, you will then come back to smoke the rest. What to call a cigarette that has been smoked by 20%? **a butt** or **a leftover cigarette**?

Loot at the cigarette that has been smoked by 20% below:
[image]

---

**Also**, about cigarette anatomy, look at the picture below:

[image]

What to call the part of a cigarette that does not contain tobacco, the yellow one which may contain some wool or cotton, do we call it "**the filter**" or "**the butt**"?

Comment: A leftover cigaret is one bought but unsmoked for some reason. The picture shows butts.

Comment: @user105719, what if you have a cigarette & you smoked by 20% of it, then stopped smoking, you then will come back to smoke the rest. What to call a cigarette that has been smoked by 20%? a butt or a leftover one?

Comment: A partially-smoked cigaret is called a *snipe* or a *short*. I think you'd have to be desperate to try to smoke a butt.

Comment: The 'snipe' and 'short' words for partly used cigarettes are informal regional dialect. In parts of the North of England, they are called _neps_.

Comment: 'Cigaret' is an old and rare US spelling; everywhere else it is 'cigarette'.

Comment: Where are you guys getting these informal names? I can't find any of them.

Comment: Slang or dialect words are not always found in dictionaries. You may disregard the slang terms mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have answered your own question. You have done good research, and it shows that "cigarette butts" is more commonly used than the other alternative.

A "butt" is *"the part of a finished cigarette that has not been smoked"* (Cambridge). Another term for this, but much less common, is "stub".

A "stub" is *"the short part of something that is left after the main part has been used, especially a cigarette after it has been smoked ..."* (Cambridge). See this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cigarette%20butts%2Ccigarette%20stubs&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccigarette%20butts%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccigarette%20stubs%3B%2Cc0) for their usage. The difference in usage between the two is smaller in BrE.

A cigarette butt may also be called a "snipe" in AmE (came across this from user105719's comment). This is a slang, so be careful if you decide to use it. See Collins [Snipe definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/snipe) no. 3 in AmE.

You can, however, write "leftover cigarette butts" depending on the surrounding text. But it is not something you will come across everyday. See [this](https://www.argusobserver.com/news/future-of-smoking-in-downtown-ontario-is-hazy/article_f44c2c62-beb8-11e9-b827-4f088ebce2fa.html), [this](https://pacificsun.com/e-cigarettes/), and [this](https://www.change.org/p/eric-garcetti-deadly-leftovers).

---

> What to call the part of a cigarette that does not contain tobacco, the yellow one which may contain some wool or cotton, do we call it "the filter" or "the butt"?

The yellow part is called "butt". The "butt" has a filter inside it and some ventilation holes on it. The outer layer of the "butt" is called "tipping paper". "Filter" is the name of the material inside the "butt".

---

> In addition, what if you have a cigarette & you smoked by 20% of it, then stopped smoking, you will then come back to smoke the rest. What to call a cigarette that has been smoked by 20%? a butt or a leftover cigarette?

If much of the tobacco is left (the white part), then it is not a butt. I would then call this a leftover cigarette, half a cigarette, or something of that sort. I am not aware of a specific term for this.

Both Kate Bunting and user105719 mention in the comments that cigarettes not used at all from a previous party/event would be called "leftover cigarettes". You may also call a cigarette with enough tobacco in it a "partially smoked cigarette".

Comment: what if you have a cigarette & you smoked by 20% of it, then stopped smoking, you then will come back to smoke the rest. What to call a cigarette that has been smoked by 20%? a butt or a leftover one?

Comment: @Tom See edited answer.

Comment: I'm not familiar with smokers' jargon, but I would call it a _partially smoked cigarette_. If someone had provided cigarettes for the guests at a party, but not all had been used, those remaining would be _leftovers_.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, that makes sense. I will edit my answer to include that bit. Thanks!

Comment: I'm coughing just from reading this topic. Yuk.